# .jar works in Windows but not Linux (stacktrace)

Tags: java, linux, jar, rhel

This is what I get:

```
[user@localhost KioskMenu]$ java -jar ./kioskmenu.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: KioskMenu (unrecognized class file version)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
[user@localhost KioskMenu]$
```

The only thing I noticed was that my RHEL is using a "free" version of Java. But this shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: I pasted the wrong code block. I edited my question.

Comment: Which Java compiler did you use, including version number?  Also, can you include the output of `java -version`?

Comment: Does the command `jar -tvf kioskmenu.jar` list the correct classes? How did you get the jar file on linux? (If ftp, did you specify binary transfer mode?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compiled the jar with a newer version of Java than the one on your Linux machine.

Comment: You're right, I compiled with 1.6 and am trying to run with 1.4. Will accept in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be doing this:

`java -jar ./kioskmenu.jar`

Notice the `-`.

If you just give `java jar ./kioskmenu.jar`, the JVM is trying to find a class named `jar` and trying to pass `./kioskmenu.jar` as an argument to it - which is clearly not what you want.